# Defining a Custom Logging Format within a Function

Tags: python, logging

I am using Python and have a logger which normally stores simple messages within the specified format:

```
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s | %(name)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s",
    handlers=[logging.FileHandler("my_log.log"),
              logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)])

def foobar():
    logging.info('foobar_invoked')
    
foobar()
```

However, there are times that I want to invoke the logger multiple times within a function, keeping the majority of the message standardized within the function, while only changing a few parts depending on what part of the function just completed.

In the example below, the only part that changes is {x, y, z}, while everything else stays standard. To me, it seems like I'm needlessly repeating `'... value set | user = %s', user`. Is there a way to make this more efficient?

```
def foobar_complex(user):
    x = 1
    logging.info('x value set | user = %s', user)
    y = 3
    logging.info('y value set | user = %s', user)
    z = 5
    logging.info('z value set | user = %s', user)
```